# Display a date field in a specific format as single line of text using calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I Need the Right Formula for the following Problem:

I got a column that contains only date but sometimes it contains no Information.

```
=DAY([AB])&"."&MONTH([AB])&"."&YEAR([AB])
```

This represents the date from column `AB` in the Right way, but if there is no Information, the result is `01.01.1899`.

What I Need is an IF Formula like:

If the column [AB] contains information -> represent it in the following way `dd.mm.yyyy` else "-" .

Maybe someone can help !

This is the data that already exist in the Date column:

[image]

Comment: Please show your formula (copy and paste here)

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK([X-first input]), "-", DAY([X-first input])&"."&MONTH([X-first input])&"."&YEAR([X-first input]))

Comment: Please try to use column name without spaces and '-'. For a test

Comment: Same result…. I think the Column Name has to be with Space, cause the original one hast a space too

=IF(ISBLANK([X-firstinput]), '-', DAY([X-firstinput])&"."&MONTH([X-firstinput])&"."&YEAR([X-firstinput]))

this was what i tried

Comment: I mean try to rename original column name.

Comment: the formula should be `=IF(ISBLANK([X-first input]),"-",DAY([X-first input])&"."&MONTH([X-first input])&"."&YEAR([X-first input]))`

Comment: Try using semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`) in your formula. refer my answer below.

Comment: The trick was to use ; instead of just ',' - Comment by @Niklas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([AB]),"-",DAY([AB])&"."&MONTH([AB])&"."&YEAR([AB]))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dear @Niklas please mark as an answer if my answer was helpful.

Comment: Is your CALC2 column a returned as 'a single line of text' ?  I tried and I got 'Sorry, something went wrong'

Comment: @Niklas yes. I.ve updated my answer.

Comment: @Niklas Yes, it has to return the type as "Single line of text" .

Comment: @Niklas please update your question with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your `AB` column is of type **Date & Time** and you have not set any default value to your column.

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([AB]),"-",DAY([AB])&"."&MONTH([AB])&"."&YEAR([AB]))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.
3. IF you have spaces in your column then wrap it inside square brackets like `[My Column Name With Spaces]`.

**References**:

1. [IS functions - ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087).
2. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.